# PHP PDO config file include - global

Tags: php, pdo

I am making a transfer from using mysql query lines to PDO for a current project and i have an issue.
For this task i am not allowed to use any classes (stupid restriction if you ask me)

Basically i was getting a non object error because my main php file could not see the set variable $DBH.
I solved this problem by setting each function with a $DBH global; so it could be used, however ive been told this is bad coding practice. Is this the case? and if so how can i make my function see my config variable.

**Config.php**

```
try 
{
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=db", "username", "Password");
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**a php file**

```
function concName($concID)
{   
        global $DBH; //THIS is the area that im told is bad practice - can this be eliminated?
        $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(`Firstname`, ' ', `Surname`) AS 'Membername'     FROM `members` WHERE `MemberID`= :MemberID");
        $stmt->bindValue(":MemberID",$concID);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            return $row['Membername'];      
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `$DBH` as a parameter to any function that needs it:

```
function concName($concID, $DBH)
{   
        $stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(`Firstname`, ' ', `Surname`) AS 'Membername'     FROM `members` WHERE `MemberID`= :MemberID");
        $stmt->bindValue(":MemberID",$concID);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            return $row['Membername'];      
        }

}
```

Rather than the `global` keyword, you can also access it from the `$GLOBALS[]` array, which is more explicit about the variable's origins when used in the function. Passing a parameter is still preferable to this though.

```
function concName($concID)
{   
        // Better than `global` keyword, use `$GLOBALS['DBH']` every time you access it in outside global scope
        // Still not preferred to passing a parameter though.
        $stmt = $GLOBALS['DBH']->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(`Firstname`, ' ', `Surname`) AS 'Membername'     FROM `members` WHERE `MemberID`= :MemberID");
        $stmt->bindValue(":MemberID",$concID);
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            return $row['Membername'];      
        }

}
```

If you have multiple globals defined in your configuration file, you can wrap them all in an array which you pass into functions needing them.  That wraps them tidily into a package of config options made available to any function that needs them.

#### config.php

```
// Global array of config options
$config = array();

// various options
$config['option1'] = 'option 1';
$config['option2'] = 12345;

try 
{
    $config['DBH'] = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=db", "username", "Password");
    $config['DBH']->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then pass `$config` to function calls

Comment: I actually get the same error when trying to pass it as a parameter, any idea why that is ?

The second option works however id obviously like to get that passing working properly

Comment: @DarkAvernus Did you remove the `global $DBH` when passing it as a param?

Comment: yes i removed the global $DBH modifying the function to function concName($concID, $DBH).
i also changed the call concName($results->getMemberID(), $DBH) to reflect the new variable

Comment: you aren't by chance calling` `concName()` _inside_ another function which doesn't know about `$DBH`, are you?

Comment: good point...  i was wondering why the this solution wouldnt work. considering that, would globals be a better method for this task or passing the variable to the top function as well

Comment: Since the bad practice in question is overuse of globals, it is better to pass it to the top function.  However, it can get unwieldy if you have more than one of them to deal with.  If it's just the one, then I would pass it along the function chain.